# Outlook 2016 meeting room schedule on SharePoint Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, outlook

I need to display the Outlook 2016 meeting room schedule on a SharePoint 2013 page (not in calendar). Getting the meeting room schedule in a SharePoint list will also work. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the Outlook 2016 meeting room schedule in the page in SharePoint 2013, then you could retrieve the meeting room schedule information from exchange server and display in the SharePoint page by custom solution.

More references:

[Get appointments and meetings by using EWS in Exchange.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-appointments-and-meetings-by-using-ews-in-exchange)

[Get room lists by using EWS in Exchange.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-room-lists-by-using-ews-in-exchange)

[Exchange 2013: Get a conference room from a room list programmatically.](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2013-Get-a-0468b925)

[Exchange 2013: Get a room list programmatically by using the EWS Managed API.](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2013-Get-a-room-0eada812)